# Usage of tag 'flight-path'

Tags: discussion, support, tags

**Flight-path** for me means trajectory through the air. But it can colloquially mean a **route.**

Since we have a [route](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/route) tag, I imagine *[flight-path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flightpath_(disambiguation))* does indeed refer to the trajectory. It does lack a tag description though.

Yet most questions for [flight-path](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-path) are about routes. So I wouldn't force a description really and retag a bunch of questions.

What should we do about it?

---

**Update after 1.5 years:** I've split the answer. The action taken (?) was opposite my recommendation *(now posted separately),* I believe in error. The flight-path tag is now the master, with the route a synonym.

Comment: When I hear flight path used in aviation it is usually referring to, either the trajectory, (i.e. "the object crossed my flight path at a 90° angle") or the track of an aircraft after the fact (i.e. during a crash investigation). I've never heard it meaning a route.

Comment: It's interesting to note that in some scientific publications, path and trajectory are NOT the same thing. Trajectory is the 3D line that an aircraft is following, Path has also a reference velocity.

Comment: I haven't looked at the questions involved, but maybe people are confusing *flight-paths* for *flight-plans*?

Comment: note that the route -> flight-path synonym suggestion has been made more than a year before you posted this question, on 2016-03-17 23:51:59 . I approved it on 2017-12-12 11:02:37 because I was not aware/did not remember this discussion. It can still be changed, as I (thankfully) did not merge at the time.

Comment: @Federico: Thank you for featuring it, it's received one UV, and a lot more users saw it in the last week. What's the plan now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the synonym link between the tags.

As a consequence of my past actions (approving the synonym on 2017-12-12 11:02:37) the [route](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/route) currently has no questions attached to it.

I can rename [flight-path](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-path) to [route](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/route), but I would prefer to do it selectively, so please feel free to edit the tag [route](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/route) wherever required.

I say so because a tag without questions will be automatically deleted during the UTC night, when an automatic chron job cleans the tag lists of every SE site. Renaming [flight-path](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-path) to [route](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/route) would leave [flight-path](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-path) without questions, and thus delete whatever wiki guidance one would put there.

Answer (score 1):

I do **not** think they should be synonyms. I originally wrote:

> I would say merge (replace and delete) flight-path into route.

Is that doable?

In detail, although actual implementation may vary as I don't know what options the mods have:

1. The synonyms to be split (no longer synonyms)
2. All flight-path questions to be tagged route

   - Rename then delete flight-path(?)
3. flight-path tag to be *added again* and to have a description for its uses, borrowing from Wikipedia as an example:

   > A trajectory or flight path is the path that a object with mass in motion follows through space as a function of time.
4. Find at least 1 question about the newly defined flight-path, and tag it to establish and reserve the tag. I was able to find three potential tag-users:

   - [What would the altitude profile for a typical airline flight look like?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53723/14897)
   - [What are the climb rates during the different phases of flight of an A320?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38471/14897)
   - [Forward slip vs side slip](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/60774/14897)

Over to you.

Comment: if you merge they have to be synonyms first. and I am not sure you can re-create the merged one afterwards. I'll ask when I have a bit of time.

Comment: This comment is way late but i must make it anyway. Route is a legal corridor like a road "route 66" or "V253"(VOR low alt routes) and "Q123"(GPS routes), flight-path is the actual [historical] path of an object, trajectory refers to potential path if no additional inputs are made.